# open flutter app when receive FCM automatically , no need to open the notification

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

i develop a flutter app for offering , FCM work well in background , what i need , to force the app open when receive the notification in background automatically
no need to open the notification or hit it , or execute a function in background also

i try this function to send notification

```
static Future<void> sendPushNotification(
      String userToken, String title, String msg) async {
    try {
      final body = {
        "to": userToken,
        "notification": {
          "title": title.toString(),
          "body": msg,
          "android_channel_id": "chats"
        },
        "data": {
          "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
          "id": "1",
          "status": "done",
        },
        "priority": "high",
      };

      var res = await post(Uri.parse('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send'),
          headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
            HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:
                'key=AAAALda61i0: .....'
          },
          body: jsonEncode(body));
      debugPrint('Response status: ${res.statusCode}');
      debugPrint('Response body: ${res.body}');
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint('\nsendPushNotificationE: $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can execute (limited) logic in a background message handler, but you can't change UI state etc., see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages). You can't force the app to open it requires the user to click on the notification.